# Heroku deplpy fails with '..bin/bundle: line 11: require: command not found... Failed to install gems via Bundler.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, bundler

Im trying to deploy my Rails api-only application to Heroku and when I run `git push heroku main`, I got this error:

```sh
Counting objects: 100% (1198/1198), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (417/417), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1198/1198), 171.98 KiB | 21.50 MiB/s, done.
Total 1198 (delta 715), reused 1188 (delta 711), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. heroku/ruby
remote:        2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.2.21
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.0.2
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.21
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        /tmp/build_814ed8d0/bin/bundle: line 11: require: command not found
remote:        /tmp/build_814ed8d0/bin/bundle: line 13: m: command not found
remote:        /tmp/build_814ed8d0/bin/bundle: line 14: module_function: command not found
remote:        /tmp/build_814ed8d0/bin/bundle: line 16: def: command not found
remote:        /tmp/build_814ed8d0/bin/bundle: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `$PROGRAM_NAME'
remote:        /tmp/build_814ed8d0/bin/bundle: line 17: `    File.expand_path($PROGRAM_NAME) == File.expand_path(__FILE__)'
remote:        Bundler Output: /tmp/build_814ed8d0/bin/bundle: line 11: require: command not found
remote:        /tmp/build_814ed8d0/bin/bundle: line 13: m: command not found
remote:        /tmp/build_814ed8d0/bin/bundle: line 14: module_function: command not found
remote:        /tmp/build_814ed8d0/bin/bundle: line 16: def: command not found
remote:        /tmp/build_814ed8d0/bin/bundle: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `$PROGRAM_NAME'
remote:        /tmp/build_814ed8d0/bin/bundle: line 17: `    File.expand_path($PROGRAM_NAME) == File.expand_path(__FILE__)'
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to murmuring-forest-17162.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-forest-17162.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-forest-17162.git'
```

My local file looks like that **bin/bundle**:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by Bundler.
#
# The application 'bundle' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

m = Module.new do
  module_function

  def invoked_as_script?
    File.expand_path($PROGRAM_NAME) == File.expand_path(__FILE__)
  end

  def env_var_version
    ENV['BUNDLER_VERSION']
  end

  def cli_arg_version # rubocop:disable Metrics/PerceivedComplexity, Metrics/MethodLength, Metrics/CyclomaticComplexity
    return unless invoked_as_script? # don't want to hijack other binstubs
    return unless 'update'.start_with?(ARGV.first || ' ') # must be running `bundle update`

    bundler_version = nil
    update_index = nil
    ARGV.each_with_index do |a, i|
      bundler_version = a if update_index && update_index.succ == i && a =~ Gem::Version::ANCHORED_VERSION_PATTERN
      next unless a =~ /\A--bundler(?:[= ](#{Gem::Version::VERSION_PATTERN}))?\z/

      bundler_version = Regexp.last_match(1)
      update_index = i
    end
    bundler_version
  end

  def gemfile
    gemfile = ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']
    return gemfile if gemfile && !gemfile.empty?

    File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)
  end

  def lockfile
    lockfile =
      case File.basename(gemfile)
      when 'gems.rb' then gemfile.sub(/\.rb$/, gemfile)
      else "#{gemfile}.lock"
      end
    File.expand_path(lockfile)
  end

  def lockfile_version
    return unless File.file?(lockfile)

    lockfile_contents = File.read(lockfile)
    return unless lockfile_contents =~ /\n\nBUNDLED WITH\n\s{2,}(#{Gem::Version::VERSION_PATTERN})\n/

    Regexp.last_match(1)
  end

  def bundler_version
    @bundler_version ||=
      env_var_version || cli_arg_version ||
      lockfile_version
  end

  def bundler_requirement
    return "#{Gem::Requirement.default}.a" unless bundler_version

    bundler_gem_version = Gem::Version.new(bundler_version)

    requirement = bundler_gem_version.approximate_recommendation

    return requirement unless Gem::Version.new(Gem::VERSION) < Gem::Version.new('2.7.0')

    requirement += '.a' if bundler_gem_version.prerelease?

    requirement
  end

  def load_bundler!
    ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= gemfile

    activate_bundler
  end

  def activate_bundler # rubocop:disable Metrics/MethodLength
    gem_error = activation_error_handling do
      gem 'bundler', bundler_requirement
    end
    return if gem_error.nil?

    require_error = activation_error_handling do
      require 'bundler/version'
    end
    if require_error.nil? && Gem::Requirement.new(bundler_requirement).satisfied_by?(Gem::Version.new(Bundler::VERSION))
      return
    end

    warn "Activating bundler (#{bundler_requirement}) failed:\n#{gem_error.message}\n\nTo install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '#{bundler_requirement}'`" # rubocop:disable Layout/LineLength
    exit 42
  end

  def activation_error_handling
    yield
    nil
  rescue StandardError, LoadError => e
    e
  end
end

m.load_bundler!

load Gem.bin_path('bundler', 'bundle') if m.invoked_as_script?
```

I have tried to change my ruby- and bundler- versions to same as Heroku uses, but result didn't change:

```
bundler -v
Bundler version 2.2.21

ruby -v
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-darwin20]

rbenv -v
rbenv 1.1.2
```

My **Gemfile**:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.2'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'dry-monads'
gem 'grape-swagger'
gem 'grape-swagger-entity'
gem 'jwt'
gem 'net-http'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4.1'
gem 'redis'
gem 'require_all'
gem 'strong_migrations'
gem 'uri'

group :development do
  gem 'database_consistency', require: false
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
  gem 'rubocop-discourse', require: false
  gem 'rubocop-rails', require: false
  gem 'spring'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'bundler-audit'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-sqlimit'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 5.0'
  gem 'webmock'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
```

In the end of my **Gemfile.lock**:

```
...


RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.0.2p107

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.21
```

I've tried (as you can see in heroku logs) to connect different ruby buildpacks, but it didn't help.

I've tried to remove **Gemfile.lock**, reinstall gems and push updated file back to main branch, but it didn't help.

I've tried to install gems locally with same command as Heroku uses (`BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4`) and push to git `vendor/bundle` folder, but it didn't help.

I've tried to run `git push heroku main:main` as logs recommends, but it didn't help.

Every time I see the same error.

Anybody has ideas, what am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The reason was in file **bin/bundle**. Since this is executable shell-file, first row here must be `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. When I removed first few excess rows, Heroku read ruby files as I expected.

This is working version of **bin/bundle**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by Bundler.
#
...
```